# Why click on optionsMenu item doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, menu, onclicklistener, optionmenu

I have a problem when clicking on an item from an options menu. I've read how to create a menu on the website https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus and I seem to do it right, but it still doesn't work. The menu exists, it is visible, but nothing happens when I perform the click. Also, there are no errors in the Logcat.

The XML file for the menu is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="@string/edit"
        android:id="@+id/edit_menu_script_item"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit"/>
    <item android:title="@string/delete"
        android:id="@+id/delete_menu_script_item"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:title="@string/share"
        android:id="@+id/share_menu_script_item"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:title="@string/scenes"
        android:id="@+id/scenes_menu_script_item"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item android:title="@string/characters"
        android:id="@+id/characters_menu_script_item"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

EDIT: Neither of the Toasts messages are displayed and the menu closes after performing click on an item.

The menu has one item on the toolbar, and the others in the dropdown menu:
[image: menu_on_toolbar]
[image: dropdown_menu]

As requested, here is the XML code for my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ViewProjectSW">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarViewProjectSW"
        app:title="@string/view_your_script"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_script"
        android:background="@color/barColor"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/textBodyColor"
        android:hint="@string/script_here"
        android:id="@+id/scriptTV"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the java class:

```
package com.stud.scriptreality;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.stud.scriptreality.classes.Screenwriter;
import com.stud.scriptreality.classes.Script;

public class ViewProjectSW extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView scriptTV;
    Intent intent;
    String title;
    Script script;
    Screenwriter screenwriter = new Screenwriter();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_project_sw);

        initialization();

    }

    public void initialization(){
        intent=getIntent();
        title=intent.getStringExtra("title");
        int id= intent.getIntExtra("position",0);
        screenwriter = intent.getParcelableExtra("autor");

        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbarViewProjectSW);
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
        script = new Script(id,screenwriter,title);

        scriptTV=findViewById(R.id.scriptTV);
        scriptTV.setClickable(false);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.menu.menu_script+"*", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_script, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.edit_menu_script_item:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opening edit page...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditScript.class);
                it.putExtra("script",script);
                startActivity(it);
                break;
            case R.id.characters_menu_script_item:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opening characters list...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent it2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewCharactersSW.class);
                startActivity(it2);
                break;
            case R.id.delete_menu_script_item:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Deleting script...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.scenes_menu_script_item:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opening scenes list...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.share_menu_script_item:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opening sharing dialog...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

I don't use the ActionBar, but another Toolbar I created, and I had set for the entire app a style with NoActionBar. `<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I'm following your description correctly. Do any of your menu items work? Is there any visual feedback at all? Does the menu close, or just stay open after the click?

Comment: None of my items work, none of the Toasts apears on the screen when clicking on the items. The menu closes after performing click.

Comment: Well, that's really odd, and I think we're going to need a [mcve], but before you dive into that, let me make sure that we're talking about [this menu dropping down from the top-right](https://developer.android.com/images/options_menu.png), yeah?

Comment: I've just added two samples with the visuals in the body of my question. It is indeed that type of menu that you suggested through that link.

Comment: OK, just wanted to check. Sometimes there's confusion about which is the options menu. Yeah, I'm afraid we're going to need more information, because those methods are both fine, in isolation.

Comment: Are you providing your own `<Toolbar>` in the layout, by chance, or is that the default `ActionBar` with your menu in it?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, I do have my own Toolbar. I edited the question again with the full code and the XML file where the Toolbar can be seen.

Comment: OK, yeah, just what I was thinking was the problem. The menu you're seeing is being inflated internally by the `Toolbar` from the `app:menu="@menu/menu_script"` attribute. It's not actually the `Activity`'s options menu. To get that functionality, first remove that attribute from the `<Toolbar>`, and then call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` in your `initialization()` method, after its `findViewById()` line. You'll probably also need to change `toolbar.setTitle(title);` to just `setTitle(title);`.

Comment: Please try the @Felipe Palma answer .. I guess it'll solve it

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I can't belive it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this line in your initialization method:

setSupportActionBar()

Well, you need to set support action bar setSupportActionBar(); and pass your toolbar variable, like this:

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
        switch(item.getItemId()){ 
            case R.id.delete_menu_script_item: 
                Toast.makeText(this, "Deleting script...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break; 
            case R.id.characters_menu_script_item:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opening characters list...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break; 
        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Cristina I created a new project & added your code. It worked fine without any problem. If it's still not working add full code of activity so I can help.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full code, also with the XML file. I don't understand why is not working for me if it worked for you.